# Does Haskell have an equivalent to Sage?

Tags: haskell, sage

Is there something like [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) for Haskell programmers?

Comment: The computer algebra system DoCon is written in Haskell, I seem to remember it was quite substantial though I've never used it and don't know its current status. http://www.botik.ru/~mechvel/welcome.eng.html

Comment: Just to agree with some other answers -- there's nothing comprehensive, just individual bits and bindings.

Comment: I once wanted to start such a project, but with my personal lack of time and the one of the few people interested in helping me, it wasn't a success...

Comment: start an open source project, i will contribute!

Comment: No, there is not. Sage is quite well-developed project with many contributors, mostly young scientists. You hardly convince these people to give it up and start contributing on another project, only because you want it to be in Haskell and not in Python. Not that I would like any of these two languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer seems to be "NO".

Possibly interesting to some readers is the following:

Often, one programming language is not enough for a task.
E.g. when I need to solve a problem which is remotely related to statistics, R ([r-project.org](http://r-project.org)) is just the best fit. But I don't want to program all code in R because, Haskell has this great type system and so many other important features.

I think the best way is a hybrid approach. I write a RESTful web service around the functionality of the R code, and with Haskell I access the web service to get or send data. (Or maybe another way to access R directly.)

Perhaps a hybrid approach with Haskell and Python+Sage makes sense.

Currently I have following three programming languages on my "stack":

- Haskell
- R (r-project.org)
- Agda (or maybe Coq)

Also possibly interesting:

In R there is a little overlap in functionality with Sage. Mainly the linear algebra, plotting functionality, and further some of the libraries (e.g. GD library) are also available in R.

Agda has some support for

1. [Algebra and Polynomials](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~nad/listings/lib-0.5/Algebra.html)
2. [Rings](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~nad/listings/lib-0.5/Algebra.RingSolver.html)

Agda should work well together with Haskell and even the syntax is very similar.
Coq can also be used with Haskell. See: [Proving "no corruption" in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7435363/proving-no-corruption-in-haskell)

I wrote "maybe" and "perhaps" because I don't know if the information is relevant to the question.

Answer (score 2):

As it was said, there is none.

However there is [Axiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_%28computer_algebra_system%29), whose language Spad is the closest too Haskell among general purpose advanced CAS's. It has strong static typing and abstraction with categories which are similar (I would say the same) as Haskell's classes.

Previously Axiom could also use Aldor which is superior to Haskell since it features dependent types. But unfortunately Aldor is dead due to licensing problems.

Be sure to check also [FriCAS](http://fricas.sourceforge.net/), Axiom's fork.

Answer (score 0):

honestly,as far as i know none exists.

But there is something called [REPA](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Numeric_Haskell%3a_A_Repa_Tutorial)

which is similar(well in a haskellish way),to numpy.

Answer (score 0):

There are two option that have been produced after hammers answer:

- [Github Ghc live](https://github.com/shapr/ghclive), [Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghclive)
- [Ghci in a new dress](https://github.com/johnfn/ghci-in-a-new-dress)

GHC live is the more recent of the two.